# Actionscript 3 Date by number

Tags: actionscript-3, date

I want to get the date by a number that I send from my server but I can't get it working it always says 1-1-1970.

This is the code that i used

```
            creationDate = new Date(Number(creationTime));
```

But now is my question wich value must the creationtime have so it has  a working date.
I tryed the timestamp and many other numbers like 01042014 but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create `Date` instance with one parameter this parameter must be the the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970 0:00:000 GMT. If you want to create 'Date' instance based of known year, month, day you need to write next:

```
var millenium:Date = new Date(2000, 0, 1); // warning: days start from 1, but months start from 0
```

Comment: Thanks I used the seconds from 1970.. :) so fixed it now to milliseconds and it works :D